# When the inverse image of an *open* set is *closed*

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. Assume that $f\colon X\to Y$ satisfies that the inverse image of any *open* set in $Y$ is *closed* in $X$ (as opposed to the definition of continuity). Can anything be said about $f$?

Comment: This would be more interesting if you came up with non-trivial examples of such functions.

Comment: Look [this](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/1996/953839/abs/), for example.